# Is there a way to have psych convert everything to a specific encoding?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have some data that I'm pulling from a database via the dbi gem.  The data returned is in ASCII-8BIT encoding.  I've stored it in a hash, and then I'm dumping it out as yaml.  Problem is, it comes out as binary yaml, like such:

```
!binary "c3RhcnRfZGF0ZQ==": !binary |-
  MjAxMy0xMC0wMQ==
```

I do not want this.  The research I've done so far suggests a few possibilities:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

This works, but as I understand it syck is no longer being maintained, so that seems less than ideal.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

But that I believe the magic encoding string doesn't work for data pulled from a database.

I've also tried taking the hash and converting all the keys and values to utf-8 via the `encode` method, but I don't love that either.  What I'd ideally like to be able to do is something like `YAML.dump(hash, :encode => 'utf-8')`, but I haven't yet found a way.  Is there any way to accomplish this specifically with the psych YAML engine?

Some quick code that demonstrates the problem:

```
require 'yaml'

key = 'abc'.encode('ASCII-8BIT')
val = 'def'.encode('ASCII-8BIT')

hash = { key => val }

puts YAML.dump(hash)
# ---
# !binary "YWJj": !binary |-
#  ZGVm
```

Comment: Error irreproducible with ruby 2.0. And with 1.9.3 the dumped data is illegible, but after `YAML::load`ing it the output is fine.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.3, and it's being loaded by another language which isn't very happy parsing it.  Plus I'd prefer it to be human readable.